# Jquery form gets send even if validation is invalid

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a form which needs to be validated before getting submitted with `axios`.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('application.store') }}" id="myForm" novalidate="">
    <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control required" placeholder="Name" autocomplete="name" required>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
       Please insert name
    </div>

    <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control required" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="email" required>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
       Please enter email
    </div>

    etc. etc

    <button type="submit" class="btn">Send</button>
</form>
```

then in my javascript I have:

```
$('button[type="submit"]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#myForm .required").each(function(e) {
        if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0) {
            $(this).addClass("is-invalid");
            $(this)
                .closest(".invalid-feedabck")
                .show();
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("is-invalid");
            sendApplication();
        }
    });

    function sendApplication() {
       // here is the axios post method...
    }
});
```

So, when one of the inputs are empty, the invalid-feedback message gets displayed but the form gets submitted anyway, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not validating as whole, a single valid validation result calls `sendApplication`. Notice, that the form is not submitted, but "_the axios post method_" is executed.

Comment: Try `<form onsubmit="return false" ...>`

Comment: @Teemu what would you suggest?

Comment: Create flag, ex. `vErrors = 0`, then increase the value if an error occurs, and call (after the loop) `sendApplication` only if the value is zero.